# PyQt5: "No Fill" in Color Dialog?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qcolordialog

I am coding a GUI in PyQt5, where I need a color picker. 
So far, I use the QColorDialog Class, which works fine for selecting a color - but my problem is that there seems to be no way to select "no color" (or "no fill", like its known from PowerPoint or Adobe Illustrator).

How to achieve to select "no color"? (The documentation only mentions a flag for transparency, but this is not helpful for me...)

Comment: The color dialog specifies a [QColor](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcolor.html). So what `QColor` would you say corresponds to "no fill", and how is it different to fully transparent?

Comment: Maybe it helps if I describe in more detail what I need: When the user selects a color, the dialog closes and a button'b background is set to that color, to indicate what color is chosen. If the user wants "no" color, I would like to have an option like in illustrator, where you click on a white icon with a thick, red line that stands for "no fill". i can imagine doing a workaround with the transparency, but I think usability-wise its an ugly construction.

Plus: i tried to set the ShowAlphaChannel-Flag, but the Dialog looks like before? Shouldn't there be a field or slider for transparency?

Comment: You didn't answer my questions at all, so I still have no idea what "no fill" is supposed to do. There's no good saying "like in Illustrator" - not everyone uses Windows, and those that do may never have used programs like that. As for the alpha channel flag: I assume you're using the native Windows color dialog, which apparently doesn't have the facility to show an alpha channnel. If you set the `ShowAlphaChannel|DontUseNativeDialog` options, it will be shown.

Comment: PS: I should also ask - why would the user need to open the **color** dialog, if they don't actually want a color? Reading between the lines, I'm guessing what you actually want to do is reset some color setting to its default value. That is, you want to allow the user to **remove** the current color settings. I think the correct way to do this is to provide an explicit "Reset Default" menu item (or whatever), rather than try to force the color dialog to do something it's not designed for.

Comment: @ekhumoro Ah, sorry, i didn't think of that. So, what I could use is that if the "no fill" would be selected, a value like "-1" (or any other code, but *not* a valid rgb color) , would be returned - then I could handle the case in my code, knowing that no filling is desired. 

I also tried DontUseNativeDialog, but nothing is changing. When I test my settings with testOption(), it evaluates True - so the Flags/Options seem to be set correctly. Maybe its a bug in pyqt5?

Comment: The bug is in your code, not pyqt5. It works perfectly fine with the options I specified in my comment above.

Comment: Ok, if yours works, I will try to find out what's wrong there. 
Anyways, I wanted to avoid making an extra "Restore Default" Button, but it seems like there is no other option than this. Thanks for your help!

Comment: If you don't mind using a non-native color dialog, it would be possible to create custom version with some extra buttons. I will post an example shortly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind using a non-native dialog, it is quite easy to customize it.

Below is a very basic implementation that shows how to embed the existing dialog, and add an extra "No Color" button at the bottom. The rest of the implementation is left as an exercise for the reader...

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets

class ColorDialog(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        widget = QtWidgets.QColorDialog()
        widget.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.Widget)
        widget.setOptions(
            QtWidgets.QColorDialog.DontUseNativeDialog |
            QtWidgets.QColorDialog.NoButtons)
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(widget)
        hbox = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        hbox.addWidget(QtWidgets.QPushButton('No Color'))
        hbox.addWidget(QtWidgets.QPushButton('Cancel'))
        hbox.addWidget(QtWidgets.QPushButton('Ok'))
        layout.addLayout(hbox)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    dialog = ColorDialog()
    dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```